# displaying jstree data from ajax is missing text

Tags: javascript, jstree

I'm trying to load an entire tree using the 'alternate method', i.e. I don't specify children, but instead specify parents.  Here's my data being sent:

```
[{"id":"0","parent":"#","text":"Chart of Accounts"},
 {"id":"1","parent":"0","text":"Assets"},
 {"id":"5","parent":"1","text":"Bank Accounts"},
 {"id":"14","parent":"5","text":"Cash Box"},
 {"id":"16","parent":"14","text":"Wallet"},
 {"id":"15","parent":"5","text":"Personal Acct"},
 {"id":"2","parent":"0","text":"Liabilities"}]
```

I have jquery code that gets executed and which loads the data (i can see it in Fiddler):

```
<div id="jstree_div"></div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#jstree_div').jstree({
            core: {
                data: {
                    url: '/api/GetEntireTree',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    plugins: [ "wholerow", "ui", "themes" ],
                    data: function(node) {
                        return { id: node.id };
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, when I set a breakpoint at function(node), node shows in the debugger as:

```
node
    children: []
    children_d: []
    id: "#"
    parent: null
    parents: []
    state: {loaded: false, failed: false, loading: true }
    [[Prototype]]: Object
```

After the breakpoint the result is it shows the first line (Chart of Accounts), but no children.  I have not found a good example of loading data via ajax using the 'alternate method'.

Here is a jsfiddle showing the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/vzqtocnh/1/

Comment: two things .. first your json data is incorrect second the code you have written is not sufficient to achieve desired result. follow the official example 

https://www.jstree.com/demo/

Comment: @Coder - are you sure about the data?  It looks identical to the data in section "Using the alternative JSON format" at https://www.jstree.com/docs/json